# Scraping comments from genius site with beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, expand

I would ask if it's possible, in your opinion, to scrape the comments from genius.com with beautifulsoup4.
I'm asking that 'cause when i scrape the page with bs4 i can't find the section of the comments as they are behind an expandable container.
If I watch the html of the page from browser I can see the comments even if I don't click on the "expand" button, but when scraping with bs4 I can't find them in the html source.

How could I resolve this problem? There is a way to scrape the comments anyways with bs4? Or should I use selenium? (I want to avoid use selenium 'cause I have to scrape a lot of data and with it selenium this could be soooo slow).

Answer (score 0):

The page most likely is JavaScript rendered. You need Selenium.if you don't want to use selenium you could pass driver.content into the BeautifulSoup method.

Here is example  code :

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.siteURL.com'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser') #or you can use lxml parser
driver.close()
```